# Bootstrap3 Navbar toggle is not working with requirejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, requirejs

I am designing a web app using BackboneJS, RequireJS and Bootstrap. When i am reducing screen size, the navbar is collapsing but the click event is not working on the toggle button.
Earlier also i had faced the same issue when i was not using RequireJS. At that time i  had included Jquery and BootstrapJS in the Head tag and it worked for me.
Now as i am using RequireJS and facing the same issue. Can anyone please help me with this?
I am attaching the config code for Require below

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: '../lib/jquery',
        underscore: '../lib/underscore',
        backbone: '../lib/backbone',
        router: 'router',
        bootstrap: "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min"
    },
    shim: {
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'bootstrap': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you get any errors on the console? Can you verify that bootstrap is actually loaded? You could verify this by checking at the console whether `jQuery.fn.popover` is defined (or `$.fn.popover`). (`popover` is just one of the additions that Bootstrap makes to jQuery when it is loaded. I'm assuming you're loading the stock Bootstrap with all its functions and not a custom version limited only to what you actually use.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it was a silly mistake. Bootstrap was not included in the module.

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'router',
  'bootstrap'
  ], 
  function ($, _, Backbone, Router) {
      var initialize = function () {
          // Pass in our Router module and call it's initialize function
          Router.initialize();
     }
  return {
      initialize: initialize
  };
});
```